# postDelayed() functionalities

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android, and I am now going through an application.
In that app I found a code line such that

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            PlayVideo(url);
                        }
                    }, 100);
```

what this means? `PlayVideo()` function will call *every* 100 milliseconds, or *after* 100 milliseconds?please help me going through it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry to be blunt but seriously, read the documentation, the method is described there. IF (and only if) there is a **specific** point in the documentation you don't understand, ask.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

Comment: sorry KMS, that's not how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

> what this means?

`postDelayed()` causes the supplied `Runnable` to be run after the specified period of milliseconds, once.

> PlayVideo() function will call every 100 milliseconds, or after 100 milliseconds?

*After* 100 milliseconds.